# Non-intersecting line segments while minimizing the cumulative length

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, geometry

I would like to find a better algorithm to solve the following problem:

There are *N* starting points (purple) and *N* target points (green) in 2D. I want an algorithm that connects starting points to target points by a line segment (brown) without any of these segments intersecting (red) and while minimizing the cumulative length of all segments.

My first effort in C++ was permuting all possible states, find intersection-free states, and among those the state with minimum total segment length  *O(n!)* . But I think there has to be a better way.

[image]

Any idea? Or good keywords for search?

Comment: Maybe some type of topological sort?

Comment: I don't know the answer either but I would create any solution (ignoring conflicts) and then resolve conflict individually: when two lines conflict, it seems that switching one pair of end points resolves the conflict. I'm not sure how to guarantee progress, though.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Switching endpoints could cause a different conflict to appear.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: yes, I realize this. That is the part about guaranteeing progress: it won't work if things are resolved in a form creating a cycle.

Comment: @Masoud M: Up to how many point-pairs do you expect to handle?

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Between 2 and 100

Comment: @MasoudM:  Wow.  Well you sure are not going to brute force solve 100 pairs, as that's Factorial(100), which is a really big number.  I'd be interested in what you decide to implement as the algorithms pointed to by qq3's reference are much better than O(n!), but also quite complicated.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is [Minimum Euclidean Matching in 2D](http://maven.smith.edu/~orourke/TOPP/P6.html). The link contains a bibliography of what's known about this problem. Given that you want to minimize the total length, the non-intersection constraint is redundant, as the length of any pair of segments that cross can be reduced by uncrossing them.

Comment: @Walkerneo, it's not crossing your legs, because the distance between your feet, and the distance between your hips is shorter than the length of your legs.

Comment: @qq3:  Strictly speaking, I think that this is *Bipartite* Minimum Euclidian Matching, a subset mentioned in your link.

Comment: @dmckee:  qq3 said that the non-intersecting rule was *redundant* under the minimum total length constraint, not "in conflict" with it (mathematically, these are *very* different things).  And for *Bipartite* problems (which this one is) locally-separable improvements are also always globally valid improvements, so the local length-crossing rule applies globally also.  (I am not sure if this applies to the non-Bipartite cases though, Bipartite is much simpler).

Comment: @RBarryYoung> Ah....my comment (which I will now delete) no longer makes sense because the comment I was responding to has been deleted. We are in agreement.

Answer (score 3):

You can select a random connection, then each time delete one cross by changing the connections of its endpoints. This operation reduces the total length (by triangle inequality). Since the number of ways of lines crossing each other is finite, in a finite number of steps we arrive at a noncrossing solution. In practice, it should converge quickly.

Comment: @MasoudM. I'm 100% sure that switching crosses finally will stop (total length decreases). If you care about the time (how many times you should do this), because your program runs on finite machines(PCs), they doesn't have something like epsilon (which could be very small), their accuracy is predefined (for example 30 bit), so it can be completed soon, Also you can add some heuristics in each step, to have better selection in changes. I suggest you implement this (you need some bases in all other algorithms like finding intersection and changing some of them are necessary in all algorithms).

Comment: Total length decreases but its finite because it at least will be zero.

Comment: @MasoudM. One useful heuristic is find all conflicts in each step and resolve them, then again search for conflicts, Also if you read qq3's suggested papers, of-course you will get better answer than this.

Comment: @MasoudM. Also if you interested in this way of problem solving, this names "Invariance" in mathematics and computer science, you can take a look at [KTH course around this](http://www.math.kth.se/~shapiro/problem.html).

Comment: This solves the problem of no intersecting line segments, but not the minimum length. Take four points of a rectangle. Selecting the two long sides creates no crosses yet is not the shortest sum of lengths.

Comment: @Chris, yes this solves first problem. See OPs comment on other answer, he was more interested in solving first part. I answered after I see his comment. Sure if he read the qq3's suggested paper he can solve it better (he first marked my answer as accepted then I suggest him to read qq3's suggested paper). actually this answer is simple algorithm and useful and I thought it can be useful for the others in future. (at least for the people who are not familiar with invariance). Also this is at most twice as optimal solution.

Comment: This is a life-saver solution! Helps me a lot in my research! Thanks!!

Comment: Would you know of any citable reference where this is mentioned: 'switching crosses causes to new cross, no matter, each time by switching one cross, you are going to minimize total length of your answer and this way can't be infinite (because total length of lines are finite)'?

Comment: Also, is it possible to prove that this works in O(F*n^2)?

Comment: @AaronJohnSabu, I've rephrased it, hopefully, it is better now. I don't know the exact time complexity, but if we look at it as a randomized las vegas algorithm, I believe it should converge very quickly. I think this algorithm is known as folklore but I don't know if there is a proper analysis of this algorithm published anywhere (if you want to refer to it somewhere, you can link it to this page as well, but I'm not the first one coming up with similar algorithm as this, it is too natural).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri thanks! Well, it's certainly going to have a time complexity less than or equal to n! since there are n! possible line combinations possible. I think I'll name it as the greedy algorithm since it reaches close to the final optimum but performing short-sighted optimizations at each step.

Comment: @AaronJohnSabu, I actually expect to see the randomized expected time of n^2 or n^3. n! cannot be even the worse case I believe, since to make the worst case, one has to start from some position X and visit almost all possible combinations while resolving the crosses. This sounds impossible and too pessimistic.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I'd love to share your belief in the algorithm being n^2 or n^3. Unfortunately, I'm struggling to find a proof for the same... I totally agree that n! is way too much to be sensible.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a you could use a [BSP-type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Following qq3's answer which says ***the intersection constraint is redundant,*** there is just one more step. Assigning starting points to end points while minimizing total length. Fortunately there is a polynomial time algorithm for this:

> [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)  is a combinatorial optimization algorithm
>   that solves the the assignment problem in polynomial time.

It reduces time order from *O(n!)* to *O(n<sup>3</sup>)*.